# Mockito - Stubbing generic Class parameter

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method which takes a Class parameter like this :

`public void check(Class<? extends A<? extends B>>);}}`

I am trying to verify that the call to the method check has been performed by the caller :

`Mockito.verify(object).check(any(Class<? extends A<? extends B>>));`

But it doesn't seem to match the parameters that "check" is expecting.

What's the right way to express this expectation using Mockito ?

Comment: I think you mean `Class.class`, but you'll have to use isAssignableFrom to actually make sure it's the type you think it is because of type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're welcome to ignore the generics if they're causing you problems. Use raw types instead.

```
verify(object).check((Class) any());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.verify(object).check((Class)any(Class<? extends A<? extends B>>));
```